# vex dialog arrive twice

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I'm using the vex dialog library (http://github.hubspot.com/vex/) to build a classic cancel-dialog:

```
 <a rel="link.php?action=cxl&id=124" title="Delete?">Delete this entry</a>

$('a.confirm').click(function() {
                var page = $(this).attr('rel');
                var text = $(this).attr('title');
                vex.dialog.confirm({
                    message: text,
                    buttons: [
                    $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.YES, {
                      text: 'No'
                    }), $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                      text: 'Yes'
                    })
                  ],
                    callback: function(value) {
                        if(value === false) {
                      //load the a href-site   
                      window.location.href = page;
                        return false;
                    } else {
                      // cancel;
                      return false;
                    }
                  }
                });
        });
```

This works fine, but sometimes when the site after the confirmation isn't loaded fast, the modal-dialog box apears again for some moments. How can i repair this?

thanks
thomas

Answer (score 0):

To prevent any kind of vex dialog from showing a second time after you changed window.location, you can do:

```
vex.dialog.alert({
  message: "Alert message",
  callback: function() {
    $(".vex").hide(); // This will hide the whole vex component
    window.location = "/";
  }
});
```